# Overreaching FDS max limit, but where?

Tags: python, sockets, recursion, file-descriptor

I have this piece of code that just downloads files from WebDav server.

_download(self) is a thread function, it is handled by multi_download(self) controller, that keeps the Thread count under 24 and it works fine. It should ensure that no more than 24 sockets are used. It is very straightforward, I am not even going to post the method here. Maybe relevant is that I am using **`Threads`**, not **`ThreadPoolExecutor`** - i am not a fan of Pool so much - handling the max ThreadCount manually.

Problem is when e.g. VPN drops and i cannot connect, or some other unhandled network problems. I could handle that ofc, but thats not the point here.

The *unexpected behaviour is HERE*:

**After a while of running retrials and logging exceptions , the file descriptor count seems to overreach the limit because it starts throwing this Error. It never happened when there was no errors/retrials in the whole process.:**
NOTE: webdav.download() library method uses `with open(file, 'wb')` to download data, so there should be no hanging FDs either.

```
2022-02-09 10:36:53,898 - DEBUG - 2294-1644212940.tdms thrd - Retried download successfull on 25 attempt         [webdav.py:_download:183]
2022-02-09 10:36:53,904 - DEBUG - 2294-1644212940.tdms thrd - downloaded 900 files                               [webdav.py:add_download_counter:67]#just a log
2022-02-09 10:36:59,801 - DEBUG - 2294-1644219643.tdms thrd - Retried download successfull on 25 attempt         [webdav.py:_download:183]
2022-02-09 10:36:59,856 - DEBUG - 2294-1644213248.tdms thrd - Retried download successfull on 25 attempt         [webdav.py:_download:183]
2022-02-09 10:36:59,905 - WARNING - 2294-1643646904.tdms thrd - WebDav cannot connect: HTTPConnectionPool(host='123.16.456.123', port=987):
Max retries exceeded with url:/path/to/webdav/file (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7b3377d898>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 24] Too many open files'))

# Marked in code where this is thrown !
```

I assume that it means i am opening too many sockets, but I tried to clean after myself, in code you can see me closing the session and even deleting the reference to client to make it more neat. BUT after a while of debugging it, I cannot seem to get hold of **WHERE** I am forgetting something and where are the hanging sockets. I try ask for help before I start counting FDs and subclassing easywebdav2 classes :) Thanks, Q.

```py
# Python 3.7.3

from easywebdav2 import Client as WebDavClient
# WebDav source:
# https://github.com/zabuldon/easywebdav/blob/master/easywebdav2/client.py


def clean_webdav(self, webdav):
"""Closing sockets after"""
  try:
    webdav.session.close()
  except Exception as err:
    logger.error(f'Err closing session: {err}')
  finally:
    del webdav


def _download(self, local, remote, *, retry=0):
"""This is a thread function, therefore raising SystemExit."""
  try:
    webdav = WebDavClient(**kw)
  except Exception as err:
    logger.error(f'There is an err creating client: {err}')
    raise SystemExit
 
  try:
    webdav.download(remote, local)   # < --------------- HERE THROWS
    if retry != 0:
      logger.info(f'Retry number {retry} was successfull')
  except(ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as err:
    if retry >= MAX_RETRY:
      logger.exception(f'There was err: {err}')
      return
    retry += 1
    self.clean_webdav(webdav)
    self._download(local, remote, retry=retry)
  except Exception as err:
    logger.error(f'Unhandled Exception: {err}')
  finally:
    self.clean_webdav(webdav)
    raise SystemExit
```

**EDIT:** Since one answer contained reference to WebDav being HTTP protocol expansion(which it is) - HTTP keep-alive should not play a role here if I am specifically closing the requests session by `webdav.session.close()` which is indeed THE requests session made by webdav. There should be no keep-alive after specifically closing right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with the WebDAV client package you're using, but any WebDAV client would usually support HTTP Keep-Alive, which means that after you release a connection, it will keep it alive in a pool for a while in case you need it again.

The way you use a client like that would be to construct *one* `WebDavClient` for your application, and use that one client for all requests.  Of course, you need to know that it's thread safe if you're going to call it from multiple download threads.

Since you are creating a `WebDavClient` in each thread, there's a good chance that total number of connections being kept alive across *all* of their pools exceeds your file handle limit.

--

EDIT: A quick look on the Web indicates that each `WebDavClient` creates a session of object from `requests`, which does indeed have a connection pool, but unfortunately isn't thread-safe.  You should create a `WebDavClient` *per thread* and use it for all of the downloads that that thread does.  That will probably require a little refactoring.

Comment: Yeah, it is not my code originally. I switched to one Client per Thread. Before it was one session for 68 threads which resulted in leaks ofc. So i switched to one client per thread/download. That is why in clean_webdav() i specificaly close the requests.session - being is here webdav.session.close(). When session is closed, there is no keep-alive right?